# C++ - How to keep a semi-random array sorted in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, sorting

I have a `for` loop in my code which generates an array of numbers each time like this:

1,2,3,4

and on next round of `for`:

2.001, 4.008, 1.002, 2.099

As you can see each element is close to a previous element but it has changed order. This loop runs thousands of time and I need to see how these values change but with them changing order it is impossible.

How to keep them sorted?

**My Attempt:**

**1-** I tried sorting them each time from the largest number to smallest with [BubbleSort](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Arrays/Bubble.htm). This would work fine if elements were all increasing or decreasing. But not when some of them increase and some decrease.

**2-** I thought of a way to store the elements of the first round of the loop and compare them to the next round and change order of the elements so they have minimum change compared to the first round and so on with next rounds. But I couldn't write a working code to do it.

**EDIT:**
My code is a very large and complicated one and I'm sure copying it does nothing but adding to the confusion. But here is a sample code of what it looks like:

```
for(x=50;x=65;x+=0.01){
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) w[i] = SomeCalculations(i);
    output<<x<<"    "<<w[1]<<endl;
    output<<x<<"    "<<w[2]<<endl;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Why do they keep changing order?

Comment: suppose in the next iteration you get `1.6 1.7 4 3` how do you know if it should be `1.6 1.7` or `1.7 1.6` ?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Actually it calculates eigenvalues of a changing matrix but I didn't want to make it complicated. The routine used to calculate them sorts them from greatest to smallest but I want them to keep their first position so I can monitor their behavior.

Comment: So what's wrong with calling `std::sort` after every iteration?

Comment: @tobi303 changes are small from an iteration to the next. small enough to be identified I think.

Comment: just sort them, if one gets bigger than a second one, then anyhow you have no chance to be ceratin which one  is which and to monitor their evolution it doesnt really matter

Comment: @Alireza Ah. Still, it'd be nice if you post some code to see if there's some way to maintain order. ;) In general, sorting will immediately be useless if the eigenvalues ever intersect each other.

Comment: @kim366 does is sort them from the greatest to the smallest? If so, as I said some of them increase and some decrease. So with this method they will change places at some level of the iteration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It's a very large code and I'm sure it will just add to the confusion. And I see your point about intersecting data.

Comment: You could perhaps monitor the differences (first-order derivative) for each eigenvalue. Then, you can continue "tracking" the eigenvalue even if it intersects by making educated guesses on whichever has the closest derivative(s).

Comment: @Alireza You choose the way it sorts them

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That's the most promising idea I think. Can you provide it in a little more detail and code as an answer?

Comment: The current code does not help with the confusion. If you ask _How to keep them sorted?_ you have to show how values from each iteration relate to each other. What does _sorted_ mean in this case?

Comment: @pingul As I mentioned they change slightly but they may intersect and by keeping them sorted I mean keep the w[1] in the first iteration w[1] in every iteration and so on.

Comment: Yes, but _why do they change order_? And what determines what is the _right_ order?

Comment: @pingul Because of the method I use to calculate them. It is not fixable. And the right order is that for example w[1]=1 doesn't change to w[1]=10 in the next iteration but change to w[1]=1.0001.

Comment: If that is the case, I must say that your example `1,2,3,4 -> 2.01, 4.08, 1.02, 2.99` is wildly misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps monitor the differences (first-order derivative) for each eigenvalue. Then, you can continue "tracking" the eigenvalue even if it intersects by making educated guesses on whichever has the closest derivative(s).

For this, we need a distance function (or cost function). One such example:

```
double dist(Eigenvalue e1, Eigenvalue e2) {
    x_dist = abs(e1.x - e2.x);
    dx_dist = abs(e1.dx - e2.dx);

    return x_dist + dx_dist;  // example distance function
}

struct Eigenvalue {
    int id;     // unique identifier for eigenvalue
    double x;   // actual value
    double dx;  // first order derivative
}
```

We now match pairs of eigenvalues which have the *least* distance between each other:

```
void track_evals(std::vector<Eigenvalues>& evals,
                 const std::vector<Eigenvalues>& old_evals) {
    // Loop through new eigenvalues (evals) and match with
    // old eigenvalues (old_evals)
    for (auto& e : evals) {
        // Find closest match
        auto old = std::min_element(old_evals.begin(), old_evals.end(),
            [e](const Eigenvalue& a, const Eigenvalue& b) {
                return dist(a, e) < dist(b, e); });

        // Match by copying identifier
        // You can use a dictionary or some other data structure,
        // if you prefer
        e.id = (*old).id;
    }
}
```

Of course, for all this to work, you need to maintain the correct values of your `Eigenvalue`s:

```
std::vector<Eigenvalue> evals;
std::vector<Eigenvalue> old_evals;

// Precompute eigenvalues
evals = SomeCalculations(0);

// Assign unique identifiers
int id = 0;
for (auto& e : evals) {
    e.id = id++;
}

// Your for loop
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    // Save old eigenvalues
    std::swap(old_evals, evals);

    // Perform SomeCalculations() and update evals
    evals = SomeCalculations(i);

    // Also update derivatives (dx) for each of the evals!
    auto old = old_evals.begin();
    for (auto& e : evals) {
        e.dx = e.x - (*old++).x;
    }

    // Track
    track_evals(evals, old_evals);

    // Sort evals into same order (if desired)
    std::sort(evals.begin(), evals.end(),
        [](Eigenvalue& a, Eigenvalue& b) { return a.id < b.id; }); 
}
```

This method is not foolproof. There may be collisions, in which case you might want to try more orders of derivatives or try to reduce the speed at which the eigenvalues change.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

```
std::sort(std::begin(w), std::end(w));

for (auto a : w) {
    output << x << "    "<< a << endl;
}
```